# Compare ElasticSearch index data with my database records

Tags: api, elasticsearch, twitter, logstash, kibana

I am streaming messages from the source into ElasticSearch, then process data with Logstash and want to compare keywords with my own database records. My question is how to compare keywords from Elastic with a keywords from database?

for e.g. I have extracted keyword "apple pie" from a streamed message and I want to look if it exist in my own database. Is it possible? and how?

Comment: What stops you from running a query on that and compare the number of results (probably filtered to a specific time range or something like that)?

Comment: This can be a solution, but I work with a large amount of data. Maybe there are any plugins? e.g. like Hadoop

Comment: Elasticsearch is a datastore. Reaching out to another datastore to compare data is not what it's built for (anything with IO or blocking behavior shouldn't be added). Logstash is the much better place — it has inputs for JDBC and Elasticsearch and you could run checks from there.